# How can I control the url path for dynamic rendering using express?

Tags: node.js, express

My problem is the following: I need to register 2 kinds of users (student and teacher), but the user controller is unique (there are just some optional values that I check on the controller according to the user form). What are my options to control what form should I render based on the request url ( or sending a variable from the route, for example).

Code below:

- newStudent and newTeacher are also my ejs CRUD files, so I just omitted them.

Routes

```
router.get('/newStudent', user_controller.user_create_get);
router.post('/newStudent', user_controller.user_create_post);

router.get('/newTeacher', user_controller.user_create_get);
router.post('/newTeacher', user_controller.user_create_post);
```

Controller

```
exports.user_create_get = function(req, res) {
    // here I would like to place an if to render newStudent or newTeacher 
    // according to the route path request

    res.render('newStudent');
    res.render('newTeacher');
}
```

Any advices are welcome. Also, should I build different controllers? Even if the register form is similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check req.path which will be /newTeacher or /newStudent like this :

```
exports.user_create_get = function(req, res) {
  if (req.path == '/newTeacher') {
    res.render('newTeacher');
  }
  else if (req.path == '/newStudent') {
     res.render('newStudent');
  }
  else {
     res.render('Error !');
  }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!